# Some items from database not being displayed in cardview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am having a problem with cardview not displaying some from the database.

My app connects to a grails back end which has a PostgreSQL db.

I have a cardview inside a recyclerview. It receives 7 values in form of JSON but on running the app, only 5 are displayed. I try doing System.out of the JSON in the stack trace and I find that all the 7 values are received so everything is okay on that front.

For clarity purposes, the fields that are not being displayed are labs("labs") and drugs administered("drugsAdministered").

Here is the main class(ClinicalHistory.java), the adapter class, the xml and the stack-trace.

ClinicalHistory.java

```
public class ClinicalHistory extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView clinicalHistory_rv;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    List<com.example.user.eafya.models.ClinicalHistory> clinicalHistory_List;
    com.example.user.eafya.models.ClinicalHistory clinicalHistory;
    ClinicalHistoryAdapter clinicalHistoryAdapter;
    private StringRequest clinicalHistoryRequest;
    private LinearLayout no_data;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ProgressDialog pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clinical_history);
        initWidgets();

        fetchData();


    }

    private void fetchData() {
        pb = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pb.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        pb.setTitle("Please wait");
        pb.setCancelable(false);
        pb.setMessage("Loading data..");
        pb.show();
        clinicalHistoryRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Configs.URL_LOGIN + Configs.CLINICALHISTORY_PATH, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String result) {
                pb.dismiss();
                System.out.print("======================================"+ result);



                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("mVisit");

                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        System.out.print("----------------"+jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("labs"));

                    }



                    Log.d("myError: ", String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));

                    if(jsonArray.length()<1) {
                        clinicalHistory_List.clear();
                        no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else if( jsonArray.length()>0){
                        if(no_data.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++){
                            JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            clinicalHistory = new com.example.user.eafya.models.ClinicalHistory();
                            clinicalHistory.setDate(data.getString("dateCreated"));
                            clinicalHistory.setHospital(data.getString("hospitalAttended"));
                            clinicalHistory.setDoctor(data.getString("attendingDoctor"));

                            clinicalHistory.setLabs(data.getString("labs"));
                            clinicalHistory.setChiefComplains(data.getString("chiefComplains"));

                            clinicalHistory.setDrugs(data.getString("drugsAdministered"));

                            clinicalHistory_List.add(clinicalHistory);
                        }
                        clinicalHistoryAdapter = new ClinicalHistoryAdapter(ClinicalHistory.this, clinicalHistory_List);

                        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ClinicalHistory.this);

                        clinicalHistory_rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        clinicalHistory_rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        clinicalHistory_rv.setAdapter(clinicalHistoryAdapter);
                        clinicalHistory_rv.setSaveEnabled(true);
                        clinicalHistory_rv.setSaveFromParentEnabled(true);
                        clinicalHistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.d("MaeraJ",e.toString());

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                pb.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClinicalHistory.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Something went wrong !!");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                dialog.setMessage("Check your data connection");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //retry
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        fetchData();
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //cancel
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                dialog.create();

                dialog.show();
                Log.d("Maera",volleyError.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(clinicalHistoryRequest);

    }

    private void initWidgets() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        no_data = findViewById(R.id.nodata_LY);
        clinicalHistory_rv = findViewById(R.id.clinicalHistory_RV);
        clinicalHistory_List = new ArrayList<>();
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refresh();
            }

        });
    }

    private void refresh() {
        try {

            clinicalHistory_List.clear();

            fetchData();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Adapter class(ClinicalHistoryAdapter.java)

```
public class ClinicalHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClinicalHistoryAdapter.myViewHolder> {
    Context ctx;
    List<ClinicalHistory> clinicalHistoryList;
    ClinicalHistory clinicalHistoryModel;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public ClinicalHistoryAdapter(Context ctx, List<ClinicalHistory> clinicalHistoryList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.clinicalHistoryList = clinicalHistoryList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView clinicalHist_date_TV,clinicalHist_hospital, clinicalHist_doctor,clinicalHist_chiefComplains, clinicalHist_labs, clinicalHist_drugs;
        ImageView clinicalHist_img;
        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            clinicalHist_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_image_IV);
            clinicalHist_date_TV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_date__TV);
            clinicalHist_hospital = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_hospital_TV);
            clinicalHist_doctor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_doctor);
            clinicalHist_chiefComplains = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_chief_complains_TV);
            clinicalHist_labs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_labs_TV);
            clinicalHist_drugs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clinicalHist_drugs_TV);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public ClinicalHistoryAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View my_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clinical_history_item,viewGroup,false);

        return new myViewHolder(my_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ClinicalHistoryAdapter.myViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
        clinicalHistoryModel = new ClinicalHistory();
        clinicalHistoryModel = clinicalHistoryList.get(position);

        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_date_TV.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getDate());
        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_hospital.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getHospital());
        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_doctor.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getDoctor());
        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_chiefComplains.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getChiefComplains());
        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_labs.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getLabs());
        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_drugs.setText(clinicalHistoryModel.getDrugs());






        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_doctor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                goToDetails(position);
            }
        });

        myViewHolder.clinicalHist_hospital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                goToDetails(position);
            }
        });
        Glide.with(ctx).load(clinicalHistoryModel.getImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.loader).error(R.drawable.header).into(myViewHolder.clinicalHist_img);



    }

    private void goToDetails(int pos) {
        clinicalHistoryModel = clinicalHistoryList.get(pos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MedicalDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("dateCreated", clinicalHistoryModel.getDate());
        intent.putExtra("clinicalHist_img", clinicalHistoryModel.getImg());
        intent.putExtra("hospitalAttended", clinicalHistoryModel.getHospital());
        intent.putExtra("attendingDoctor", clinicalHistoryModel.getDoctor());
        intent.putExtra("chiefComplaints", clinicalHistoryModel.getChiefComplains());
        intent.putExtra("labs", clinicalHistoryModel.getLabs());
        intent.putExtra("drugs", clinicalHistoryModel.getLabs());
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return clinicalHistoryList.size();
    }
}
```

The xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="4dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView

                    android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_image_IV"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/header" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_date__TV"
                        android:text="21/09/2012"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_hospital_TV"
                        android:text="Hema Hospital"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_doctor"
                            android:text="Dr.Lilian"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_labs_TV"
                        android:text=" Brucella "
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />





                    <TextView
                           android:layout_gravity="center"
                           android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_chief_complains_TV"
                           android:text=" Headache "
                           android:textColor="#000"
                           android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/clinicalHist_drugs_TV"
                        android:text=" Brufen "
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The stack trace

```
I/System.out: ======================================{"mVisit":[{"id":1,"chiefComplains":"Headache","dateCreated":"2017-08-11T21:00:00Z","labs":"Brucella","hospitalAttended":"Hema Hospital","drugsAdministered":"Tramadol","attendingDoctor":"Dr. Kisinga"
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the class `ClinicalHistory`?

Comment: Also it'd be better to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for all textviews that are inside the `LinearLayout` instead of `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was in the model.

This was my previous model. Note the parameters in the 
setDrugs() and setLabs().

```
public class ClinicalHistory {
    String img;
    String date;
    String labs;
    String hospital;
    String chiefComplains;
    String doctor;
    String drugs;


    public ClinicalHistory() {
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getHospital() {
        return this.hospital = hospital ;
    }

    public void setHospital(String hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

   public  String getChiefComplains(){return this.chiefComplains = chiefComplains;}

   public void setChiefComplains(String chiefComplains){ this.chiefComplains = chiefComplains;}


    public String getLabs() {
        return this.labs = labs ;
    }

    public void setLabs(String hospital) {
        this.labs = labs;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return this.doctor = doctor ;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public void setDrugs(String hospital) {
        this.drugs = drugs;
    }

    public String getDrugs() {
        return this.drugs = drugs ;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

After I made this change it worked

```
public class ClinicalHistory {
    String img;
    String date;
    String labs;
    String hospital;
    String chiefComplains;
    String doctor;
    String drugs;


    public ClinicalHistory() {
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getHospital() {
        return this.hospital = hospital ;
    }

    public void setHospital(String hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

   public  String getChiefComplains(){return this.chiefComplains = chiefComplains;}

   public void setChiefComplains(String chiefComplains){ this.chiefComplains = chiefComplains;}


    public String getLabs() {
        return this.labs = labs ;
    }

    public void setLabs(String labs) {
        this.labs = labs;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return this.doctor = doctor ;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public void setDrugs(String drugs) {
        this.drugs = drugs;
    }

    public String getDrugs() {
        return this.drugs = drugs ;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```